# python3 curses addstr in pad not shown in iteration loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

**Created with these:**

```
self.pads = []
self.pads.append( [ server, channel, curses.newpad(height - 2, width) ] )
```

**The problem function:**

```
def writepad(self, server, channel, message): # Write a line on-to pad, but do not switch pad_num (current pad)
    (height, width) = self.stdscr.getmaxyx() # Conserve code.
    self.stdscr.addstr('%s\n' % str(self.pads)) # debug
    for i in self.pads:
        if i.count(server) and i.count(channel):
            i[2].addstr('%s\n' % message)
            #i[2].refresh(1, 0, 0, 0, height - 2, width) # propably useless
            self.stdscr.addstr('debug: %s\n' % message)
    #self.stdscr.refresh() # propably useless
```

**The output:**

```
[['main', 'µIRC', <_curses.curses window object at 0x7f73ff5a6b70>]]
debug: use /connect <server address>[:<server port>]
```

**The problem:**

Pad addstr is not printing anything visible. I'm using python3.3.

Answer (score 0):

no "refresh" was done for the "pad"

```
        i[2].addstr('%s\n' % message)
        #i[2].refresh(1, 0, 0, 0, height - 2, width) # propably useless
        self.stdscr.addstr('debug: %s\n' % message)
```

It appears that python's curses binding does not distinguish pads and windows.  If that were C, and if that is really a curses **pad**, you would use `pnoutrefresh` before the `refresh` for *stdscr*.  But [wnoutrefresh](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.noutrefresh) is analogous. A simple

```
        i[2].wnoutrefresh()
```

before the

```
        self.stdscr.addstr('debug: %s\n' % message)
```

is probably what was intended.